# Strange behavior when combining CONVERT(CHAR()) with RIGHT()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, number-formatting

When I was trying to create a report that included a decimal-implied number column that needs to be a fixed length of six characters, I chose to go the route of converting to char, replacing the decimal with '', and then using RIGHT() to pad zeros on the left hand side, turning `15.52` into `001552`, `1.11` into `000111`, etc...  My code looked like:

```
  SELECT RIGHT( '000000' + REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(8), ISNULL([TotalModePremium], 0)), '.', ''), 6) AS TotalModePremium
  FROM <Database>.<Schema>.<Table>
```

This created unexpected behavior where it would clip off my results, making a max length of 3 characters. `15.52` would become `552`. However, rows with `0` would become `00`--only two characters. When I would change the CHAR(8) to CHAR(7), `15.52` would become `1552`, but `0` would become `000`.

*I then change the CHAR(n) to VARCHAR(n), and it now works as desired*. `15.52` becomes `001552`, `0` becomes `000000`, etc...

My question is, why would increasing or decreasing the value in CHAR(n) create those sorts of results when combined with the RIGHT() function to pad zeros, but the use of VARCHAR() eliminates that behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because of how the `CHAR` data type works.

Take a look at this example:

```
 DECLARE @d decimal(15,2)
 SET @d = 15.52

 SELECT CAST(@d AS CHAR(8)) AS CharD
 SELECT DATALENGTH(CAST(@d AS CHAR(8))) AS LengthCharD

 SELECT CAST(@d AS VARCHAR(8)) AS VarcharD
 SELECT DATALENGTH(CAST(@d AS VARCHAR(8))) AS LengthVarcharD
```

Notice the length of `@d` is 8 when it's `CHAR` but 5 when it's `VARCHAR`. `CHAR` is fixed width and thus padded with blanks.

Once you add '000000' to it and remove the decimal, you've now got a 13 character string: '0000001552< blank>< blank>< blank>. 
When the `RIGHT` function gets just the right 6 characters, the result is 552< blank>< blank>< blank>.

'000000' is `VARCHAR`. `VARCHAR` + your `CHAR` string will result in a `VARCHAR` string but still includes the blanks from the `CHAR`.

`VARCHAR` does not pad with blanks and thus avoids this < blank> issue.